# Cómo podría hacer una función que recibe un vector de números reales y un número real x

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos

Estoy empezando a aprender python y tengo el siguiente problema:

Desarrolle una función que reciba un vector de números reales y un número real x, tal que
indique el porcentaje de elementos menores a un valor x.

He intentado hacer varias funciones, pero ninguna ha tenido éxito.

```
def vector(*numeros):
porcentaje = 0
for x in numeros:
    porcentaje = x/vector * 100
print(porcentaje)
```

Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: Hola y bienvenida a [es.so]. Dale a [edit](/edit) para añadir el código de lo que has intentado. Revisa el apartado [ask] para crear una publicación que sea de mayor interés y así encontrar una respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: Listo! Ya lo agregue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero vamos a analizar tu intento:

tu función es definida con:

```
def vector(*args)
```

por lo que defines una función llamada `vector` que recibe un número indeterminado de argumentos posicionales.

Si analizas el enunciado, dice:

> reciba un vector de números reales y un número real x

en Python por "vector de reales" podemos entender una lista/tupla de floats, además debes recibir `x` como argumento también. Por lo tanto, tu función debería ser algo así:

```
def porcentaje_menores(numeros, x):
```

Volviendo a tu intento, declaras `porcentaje = 0` como un acumulador, lo cual en principio sería correcto. Posteriormente usas un `for in`  para recorrer números (tupla), siendo la idea esencialmente correcta también, pero luego haces:

```
porcentaje = x/vector * 100
```

primero de todo, `x` no está definido en ningún lado, debería recibirlo como parámetro la función como se ha comentado. Luego divides `x` entre cada numero cuando el enunciado dice:

> elementos menores a un valor x

deberías **usar un condicional y comprobar que cada numero es o no menor que `x`**. Si el número lo es, lo agregas al contador y al terminar el `for` calculas el porcentaje dividiendo  el número de reales que son menores a `x` entre la cantidad total de números del vector y multiplicando por 100. Dicho porcentaje lo debe retornar la función.

En definitiva, la función debería quedar como:

```
def porcentaje_menores(numeros, x):
    menores = 0
    for numero in numeros:
        if numero < x:
            menores += 1
    porcentaje =  menores / len(numeros) * 100
    return porcentaje

>>> porcentaje_menores([3.5, 7, 9, 3.7, 4.5, 2, 6, 2.8], 3.6)
37.5
>>> porcentaje_menores([3.5, 7, 9, 3.7, 4.5, 2, 6, 2.8], 3)
25.0
```

Otra forma más concisa y eficiente es usar un generador junto al built-in `sum`:

```
from typing import List


def porcentaje_menores(números: List[float], x: float) -> float:
    return sum(número < x for número in números) / len(números) * 100
```